# using margin minus is right approch?

Tags: html, css

I have this code which was working fine but commonly (not for this code specifically) my senior developer told me to avoid minus values on margin.

```css
#speech-bubble {
   margin:100px;
   width: 120px; 
   height: 80px; 
   background: blue;
   position: absolute;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
   border-radius: 10px;
}
#speech-bubble:before {
   content:"";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 13px solid transparent;
   border-right: 26px solid blue;
   border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
   margin: 13px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="speech-bubble">
  </div>
</body>
```

1. Why do I need to avoid negative values on margin?
2. If I removed content:"" my code not working but I think it's an unnecessary line.
3. What does this do? After I remove it from my code, things work?

   `-moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;`

Comment: `my senior developer told me to avoid minus` so ask him why ... i don't  see the issue of using negative values since they are allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.my question is Why need to avoid negative values on margin?

Negative margins are counter-intuitive with the normal concept of margins being the space around an element. Negative margins are technically fine, but makes the code harder to read and maintain. If there is an alternate way that's more straight forward its better to use it.

> 2.if I removed content:"" my code not working but I think its unnecessary line..

`:before` and `:after` creates pseudo-elements in `HTML` if a `content` is defined. If you don't provide a `content` there is probably nothing to show in the pseudo-element.

Check the [specs here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) the default value for `content` is `none` which should not generate a `pseudo-element`.

You will have to use `''` a null string if you dont need any content in the element.

> 3. what does -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; after i removed this from my code it working fine :)

`border-radius` can be googled to get the meaning, `-moz`, `-webkit`, `-ms`, `-o` etc are browser prefixes for experimental rules that browsers introduce before a specification is ratified. `-moz-border-radius` is so like a pre-release version on `border-radius` that older versions of gecko based browsers supported. Most recent browsers support these rules without any browser prefix.

Comment: how can that 1 line code(-mos,-webkit) solve browser compatibility issues? may I know more depth knowledge or any link regarding this

Comment: @SelvaGanapathi These are called "browser prefixes in css" you can just search that in google and you will get all the details from different articles. There is no single link that explains everything.

Answer (score 1):

1. Negative margins are confusing (they are counter intuitive, not clearly marked on browser inspector tool, etc.) and should be avoided whenever possible. You should use top/bottom/left/right when you are using `absolute` positioning.
2. `content:''` is needed for pseudo elements (`before` and `after`) to give them content (without it they do not exists and cannot be styled). You can put some content there like this `content:'someconent'`
3. When feature in browser is in experimental state it sometimes available with prefixed format (like `-webkit-border-radius`), and later it's changed to `border-radius`. This way you can use different values for experimental and final version. This is most visible in flexbox as it was changed many times. `border-radius` on other hand was not changed so you put `-webkit-border-radius` for older browsers which use it experimental version and `border-radius` for modern browsers which use final version.

Comment: so those webkit are used for  avoid browser combability  issues ,am I right

Comment: Yes. You can check what browsers support which feature and if they require feature on https://caniuse.com . For example https://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius (if you click 'show all'  you can see browsers which used prefixes for border-radius are long gone so those prefixes are no longer needed)